# How to load data from database when the node server start

Tags: node.js

I want to load some data from database to cache when the node server start,but I am not sure how to implement it:

I have though this:

load.js:

```
var connection=require('mysql');
var loader=function(){
  connection.query('sql',function(err,rows){
    cache.put('data',rows);
  });
};

loader();
module.exports={}; //export nothing
```

Then I have two questions:

1 Is this the node way to do the job?

2 The load process is async, which means once the file is loaded(by the `require` command), the load job may not be completed. I need something like the servlet initialization work in JavaEE. The server will start only after the job done.

Is this possible?

Comment: can you post the server.js (aka init file) file?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to perform initialization tasks in node

**app.js**

```
var project = require('project');  //  assuming project.js contains your project code

function initializationTasks(callback){
    // perform all initialization tasks e.g. read from database

    callback();
}

initializationTasks(project.start);  // start executing your project
```